# Grails 2.3.6 not throwing optimistic exceptions

Tags: grails

I have a scaffolded domain class and I am trying to get it to throw an optimistic locking exception, but it won't. I put the same instance in edit mode in two different browsers. I edit a field in browser 1 and click update. I verified that the version increments. I then edit in browser 2 and click update. It just overwrites the browser 1 changes with the browser 2 changes. I've seen many questions here about people getting the exception when they don't want it, so I am wondering if they turned it off in Hibernate somehow. I even tried changing the update method so all it does is execute instance.save(). Am I not understanding what optimistic locking is supposed to do?

```
package demo
class issue {
    String synopsis
    String details

    static constraints = {
        synopsis()
        details(size: 0..1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have the 'version' field in place for this domain class. Could you please post the domain class with its relationships?

Comment: @FranGarcía - thanks for the reply. It is a simple class with just two text  fields and no relationships. I verified with dbconsole that the version column was implemented and that it increments with each save.

Comment: are you using the scaffolded controller or your own?

Comment: @injecteer - I am using the scaffolded controller. I tried it with the scaffolded udpate() method, and then commented out everything except for the issueinstance.save(flush:true) command and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried Grails 2.3.x, but in versions up to 2.2.4 the version check is happening exactly in `update` action and not deep inside hibernate:

```
def update(Long id, Long version) {
    def priceInstance = Price.get(id)
    //..
    if (version != null) {
        if (priceInstance.version > version) {
            priceInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                      [message(code: 'price.label', default: 'Price')] as Object[],
                      "Another user has updated this Price while you were editing")
            render(view: "edit", model: [priceInstance: priceInstance])
            return
        }
    }

    priceInstance.properties = params

    if (!priceInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [priceInstance: priceInstance])
        return
    }
    ...
  }
```

if you are not using that or similar code, GORM stores the instance as it is without checking for version

Comment: I remember seeing that in scaffolded controllers prior to 2.3. I should probably file a bug against the docs: "When you perform updates Hibernate will automatically check the version property against the version column in the database and if they differ will throw a StaleObjectException. This will roll back the transaction if one is active."